# Meteor Session is not defined

Tags: session, meteor

when I run my meteor project, this problem occurred:

```
ReferenceError: Session is not defined
at app/_components/talk/views/friends_list.coffee.js:1:16
at /home/xyz/web/edp/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:298:12
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/xyz/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/
    meteor/9bb2b5447e845c4f483df5e9b42a2c1de5ab909b/
    dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:78:11)
```

here is my directory structure (I have changed the name of the files):

```
├── _components
│   ├── project_form
│   │   └── client
│   │       ├── lib
│   │       │   └── ...
│   │       ├── project_info
│   │       │   ├── x1.coffee
│   │       │   ├── x2.html
│   │       │   ├── x3.coffee
│   │       │   └── x4.html
│   │       └── views
│   │           ├── x5.coffee
│   │           └── x6.html
│   ├── README.md
│   └── talk
│       └── client
│             ├── x7.coffee
│             ├── x8.html
│             ├── x9.coffee
│             ├── x10.html
│             ├── x11.coffee
│             ├── x12.html
│             ├── x13.coffee
│             ├── x14.html
│             └── x15.less
```

If I change the directory structure to the following, 
meteor runs correctly.I really don't know why, how could it happened?
I think the file loading order may make a difference to it.
But I can't figure it out.

```
├── _components
│   ├── project_form
│   │   └── client
│   │       ├── lib
│   │       │   └── ...
│   │       ├── project_info
│   │       │   ├── x1.coffee
│   │       │   ├── x2.html
│   │       │   ├── x3.coffee
│   │       │   └── x4.html
│   │       └── views
│   │           ├── x5.coffee
│   │           └── x6.html
│   ├── README.md
│   └── talk
│       └── client
│           └── views
│               ├── x7.coffee
│               ├── x8.html
│               ├── x9.coffee
│               ├── x10.html
│               ├── x11.coffee
│               ├── x12.html
│               ├── x13.coffee
│               ├── x14.html
│               └── x15.less
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This might be happening because `Session` only works on the client and at `app/_components/talk/views/friends_list.coffee.js` it would also be run on the server.

You might want to move all your views/client side stuff into the `/client` directory or place it in:

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {

}
```

Answer (score 74):

While the above is correct, if you are using newer versions of Meteor, Session is no longer supported by default. Stop your server, open terminal and write:

```
meteor add session
```

---

If you’re looking for ReactiveVar and ReactiveDict, same issue. Open terminal and write:

```
meteor add reactive-var reactive-dict
```

Comment: You need to go to terminal and navigate the meteor project and run the command line  "meteor add session"

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. I was curious whats happened in the first 5 minutes, but that fixed my problem. 
You can add also the session package, when you include session in .meter/packages

Comment: I guess this is to motivate people to use reactiveVars instead. Currently, there is a misuse of the Session package by the community.

Comment: @FranciscoGutiérrez I highly agree. Here is a fantastic tutorial for anyone looking to start using ReactiveVars and Dicts instead of sessions exclusively: https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/reactive-dict-reactive-vars-and-session-variables/#tmc-takeaways

Answer (score 10):

---

### **As per latest Meteor ^1.5.1**

goto **`.meteor/packages`** file and add **`session`** at the last line.

> **NOTE**: It does not matter whether your meteor server was UP or NOT.

---

### **Old Answer**

Stop the meteor server and run below command.

```
meteor add session
```

Answer (score 2):

This happend to me after i deployed to [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) with [mupx](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx).

**Session** worked when developing on localhost, but after deploying i got `ReferenceError: Session is not defined`

> Error was fixed after adding `session` to meteor packages and redeployed.

Comment: Do you have a link to a good tutorial for deploying a meteor app to DO?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nz2p9xIT2es : Deploy Meteor App with mupx . Sadly it only works for Meteor version 1.3.5 and below.