# Meteor: Session is not defined

Tags: javascript, session, meteor

I am learning meteor and following [this](http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/sessions/) link.

When I use `Session.set`  it gives me error `Session is not defined` in console

My code of main.js file within client folder is following

```
PlayersList = new Meteor.Collection('players'); 

 if(Meteor.isClient) {
     Template.leaderboard.events({
        'click .playerName  ': function(){
            var playerId = this._id;
            Session.set('selectedPlayer', playerId);
        }
     });
 }
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092565/meteor-session-is-not-defined) post.

My file is inside client folder and code also inside `isClient` condition.
Still it giving me error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The session package isn't installed by default anymore. You just need to run:

```
meteor add session
```